# How can I use multicast in a Win7 VM on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, qt, virtualbox, multicast

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop to host a Windows 7 VirtualBox instance. What I want to do is connect the laptop to a network (either wired or wireless) then run an app in the Windows VM that connects to an IPv4 multicast. The app is written in Qt 4.8.2 and I'm running it in QtCreator. When I run the app it fails to join the multicast group:

```
QUdpSocket *udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
bResult = udpSocket->bind(port, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);
bResult = udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(address);
```

If I step into joinMulticastGroup() I can see setsockopt() returns -1. This code works fine in native Windows. I've tried attaching the VM network to NAT or a Bridged Network to eth0 (with Promiscuous Mode set to Allow All) but neither works.

Does VirtualBox just not allow this or is there some setting somewhere I need to adjust, either in the VM or on the Linux host?

Note: I can't run the Qt app in Linux because it depends on third-party libraries that are only built for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I fixed it accidentally by following up on a USB problem I was having - thanks to [Ramon Suarez](https://askubuntu.com/users/42485/ramon-suarez) for his answer to [VirtualBox doesn't recognize USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140081/virtualbox-doesnt-recognize-usb/147791#147791).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: The answer is to a different question, I was providing a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting Promiscious Mode to "Allow All" on the VMs network adapter in Virtualbox.